# Get record by one part of complex keyPath Yathit (or indexeddb)

Tags: indexeddb

I have an indexeddb store of messages that use a keyPath of [contact_id, datetime]

What I am struggling to get to grips with is how to construct a query that would let me pull back all records where the contact_id = some value.

1: Am I approaching this the correct way. I only ever need to search records based on the contact_id. The datetime I added to make the record distinct as they do need to be updated occassionally.

2: How can I retrieve a record by contact_id? (either Yathit or indexeddb example would be fantastic.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the contact id property and then iterate over the index.

In onupgradeneeded

```
messageStore.createIndex('contact_id_index','contact_id');
```

In your query code

```
function selectMessagesByContactId(db, contactId, 
    perMessageHandler, onIterationCompleted) {

  var tx = db.transaction('messages');
  tx.oncomplete = onIterationCompleted;
  var store = tx.objectStore('messages');
  var index = store.index('contact_id_index');
  var range = IDBKeyRange.only(contactId);
  index.openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(event) {
   var cursor = event.target.result;
   if(cursor) {
     perMessageHandler(cursor.value);
     cursor.continue();
   }
  };
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid using an index, just use `var range= IDBKeyRange.bounds([contactId,MIN_DATE],[contactId,MAX_DATE])` and `store.open(range)`.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I can't test this until tomorrow am, but I will be sure to update this answer accordingly.